if $M\cong M'$ and $N\cong N'$ as $R$-modules then when we have $M/N\cong M'/N'$?
Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $N\subseteq M$ and $N'\subseteq M'$ be $R$-modules with $M\cong M'$ and $N\cong N'$. Is it true that $M/N\cong M'/N'$?
As I know it is not true if we take $R=\mathbb{Z},N=2\mathbb{Z},N'=3\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=M'=\mathbb{Z}$.
But in some textbook it says that when $R$ is a PID, if $M\cong M'$ are finitely generated $R$-modules, then $\mathrm{Tor}(M)\cong\mathrm{Tor}(M')$ and $M/\mathrm{Tor}(M)\cong M'/\mathrm{Tor}(M')$. I am confused that how the authors obtain $M/\mathrm{Tor}(M)\cong M'/\mathrm{Tor}(M')$ only by the two isomorphisms.
So what additional conditions should I add to make the argument "Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $N\subseteq M$ and $N'\subseteq M'$ be $R$-modules with $M\cong M'$ and $N\cong N'$. Then $M/N\cong M'/N'$?" be true?

@DietrichBurde Sorry, I forgot to add the conditions of isomorphisms, and I have corrected it now.

If there is an isomorphism $M\to M'$ such that $f(N)=N'$, then $M/N\cong M'/N'$, I guess.

With $N=Tor(M)$ we have $M\cong N\oplus M/N$. However, this is not true in general. For your example, it would be $\Bbb Z\cong 2\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

This is because Tor is a functor. This means that every linear map of modules $M \to N$ induces a linear map between the submodules $\mathrm{Tor}(M) \to \mathrm{Tor}(N)$. Moreover, this construction is compatible with composition. Hence, if $M \to N$ is an isomorphism, then the induced map $\mathrm{Tor}(M) \to \mathrm{Tor}(N)$ is an isomorphism as well. You can either prove this directly or by referring to the general fact that functors preserve isomorphisms. The latter has the advantage that you can apply it in thousands of scenarios. It also answers your question about $M / \mathrm{Tor}(M)$.
Coming back to the observation that the quotient operation doesn't seem to preserve isomorphisms, and hence cannot be functorial: this just because we didn't choose the right morphisms. Instead, we should define a morphism $(M,N) \to (M',N')$ to be a linear map $M \to M'$ that restricts to a linear map $N \to N'$. In that case we have an induced linear map $M / N \to M' / N'$, so indeed we have a functor that maps $(M,N)$ to the quotient $M/N$. It follows that if $M \to M'$ is an isomorphism that maps $N$ onto $N'$ (this is the additional requirement you asked for), we get an induced isomorphism $M / N \to M' / N'$.

Shouldn't we also say in the first paragraph that the inclusion $\operatorname{Tor}(M) \to M$ is natural, which makes $M \mapsto M/\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ functorial as well?
